# Different sibling angles at the same level when using mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I tried now for some time to figure out how to use different sibling angles for different nodes at the same level of a mind map. The sibling angles should be customized. Here is my example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white, level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=52mm, sibling angle=100}, level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=40}]
node[concept] {Parent}
[clockwise from=-40]
child[concept color=blue] {
  node[concept] {Child 2}
  [clockwise from=60]
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 1}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 2}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 3}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 4}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 5}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 6}}}
child[concept color=green!60!black] {
  node[concept] {Child 1}
  [clockwise from=0]
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 1}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 2}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 3}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 4}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 5}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 6}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 7}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 8}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The sibling angle of child 1 looks ok, but I would like to change the sibling angle of child 2 to spread the grandchildren out more evenly. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just so you know, you can edit your question even after you've posted it. Also, it would be helpful if you could turn this into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). That is, complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

You can change the sibling angle of level 2 in the keywords of child 2:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white,
  level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=52mm, sibling angle=100},
  level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=40}]
node[concept] {Parent}
[clockwise from=-40]
child[concept color=blue] {
  node[concept] {Child 2}
  [clockwise from=85, level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=50}]
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 1}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 2}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 3}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 4}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 5}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 6}}}
child[concept color=green!60!black] {
  node[concept] {Child 1}
  [clockwise from=0]
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 1}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 2}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 3}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 4}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 5}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 6}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 7}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 8}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to define the circularly even distribution of level 2.

```
set angles for level/.style={level 2/.append style={sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}},
level/.append style={set angles for level=2}
```

Then adjust the starting angle for grandchildren respectively to prevent overlapping of branches and grandchild nodes via `[clockwise from=starting angle]` where grandchild 1 always has starting angle of 0.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,arrows,mindmap}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap, concept color=black, text=white, 
level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=60mm, sibling angle=100}, 
%level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=40}
set angles for level/.style={level 2/.append style={sibling angle=360/\the\tikznumberofchildren}},
level/.append style={set angles for level=2}
]

node[concept] {Parent}
[clockwise from=-40]
child[concept color=blue] {
  node[concept] {Child 2}
  [clockwise from=-8]
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 1}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 2}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 3}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 4}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 5}}
  child {node[concept] {Grandchild 6}}
}
child[concept color=green!60!black] {
  node[concept] {Child 1}
  [clockwise from=18]
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 1}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 2}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 3}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 4}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 5}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 6}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 7}}
  child{node[concept] {Grandchild 8}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```